# nome.exe parou de funcionar. Não consigo corrigir isso

Tags: c, arquivo, algoritmo-de-busca, alocação, árvore

Meu código em C dá um *crash* exibindo po seguinte erro:

> nome.exe parou de funcionar

Não sei como corrigir isso. Segue o código que já fiz:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct no{
    int id;
    char* nomeCompleto;
    char* apelido;
    char* partido;
    char* cargo;
    float valorPropina;
    int qtdVezes;
    //Partido* partido;

    struct no* esq;
    struct no* dir;

}No;

No* criarNo(int id, char* nomeCompleto, char* apelido, char* cargo, float valor, int qtdDeVezes){
    No* no = (No*)malloc(sizeof(No));
/*
    printf("id: ");
    scanf("%d", no->id);

    printf("Nome do politico: ");
    gets(no->nomeCompleto);

    printf("Apelido do politico: ");
    gets(no->apelido);

    printf("Cargo do politico: ");
    gets(no->cargo);

    printf("Valor da propina: ");
    scanf("%d", no->valorPropina);

    printf("qtd: ");
    scanf("%d", no->qtdVezes); */
    strcpy(no->nomeCompleto, nomeCompleto);
    strcpy(no->apelido,apelido);
    //p->partido = partido;
    strcpy(no->cargo,cargo);
    no->valorPropina = valor;
    no->qtdVezes = qtdDeVezes;
    no->id = id;

    no->esq = NULL;
    no->dir = NULL;
    return no;
}

No* inserirPolitico(No* raiz, int id, char* nomeCompleto, char* apelido, char* cargo, float valor, int qtdDeVezes){
    No* novo = criarNo(id, nomeCompleto, apelido, cargo, valor, qtdDeVezes);
    if(raiz == NULL) return novo;

    No* no = raiz;
    No* pai = NULL;
    while(no != NULL){
        pai = no;
        if(novo->id < no->id) no = no->esq;
        else no = no->dir;
    }

    if(pai->id > novo->id) pai->esq = novo;
    else pai->dir = novo;

    return raiz;
}

/*
void salvarArquivo(No* no){
    salvarArquivo(no->esq);
    FILE* file;

    file = fopen("ed.txt", "w");
    salvaItem(no, file);

    fclose(file);
    salvarArquivo(no->dir);
}

void salvaItem (No* p, FILE *file){
    if(p->esq)salvaItem(p->esq,file);
    fprintf(file, "%d %s %s %s %d %d\n", p->id, p->nomeCompleto, p->apelido, p->cargo, p->valorPropina, p->qtdVezes);
    if(p->dir)salvaItem(p->dir,file);
}
*/

void imprimirOrdem(No* raiz){
     if(raiz != NULL){
        imprimirOrdem(raiz->esq);

         FILE* file;

        file = fopen("ed.txt", "w");
        //printf("%d - ", raiz->chave);
        fprintf(file, "%d %s %s %s %2f %d\n", raiz->id, raiz->nomeCompleto, raiz->apelido, raiz->cargo, raiz->valorPropina, raiz->qtdVezes);

         fclose(file);

        imprimirOrdem(raiz->dir);
     }
}

int main(){

    No* no =  (No*) malloc(sizeof(No));
    no->nomeCompleto = malloc(sizeof(char));
    no->apelido = malloc(sizeof(char));
    no->cargo = malloc(sizeof(char));



    /*
    printf("id: ");
    scanf("%d", no->id);

    printf("Nome do politico: ");
   gets(no->nomeCompleto);
   // scanf("s", no->nomeCompleto);

    printf("Apelido do politico: ");
    gets(no->apelido);
    //scanf("s", no->apelido);

    printf("Cargo do politico: ");
    gets(no->cargo);
    //scanf("s", no->cargo);
    printf("Valor da propina: ");
    scanf("%d", no->valorPropina);

    printf("qtd: ");
    scanf("%d", no->qtdVezes);

    inserirPolitico(no, no);
    imprimirOrdem(no);
    */
    no->nomeCompleto = "sSASs";
    no->apelido = "scscscs";
    no->cargo ="ddd";
    no->id = 1;
    no->valorPropina = 22.0;
    no->qtdVezes =2;

    inserirPolitico(no, no->id, no->nomeCompleto,  no->apelido, no->cargo, no->valorPropina, no->qtdVezes );
    imprimirOrdem(no);


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Você consegue debugar o programa para ver em qual linha ele dá o erro?

Comment: Coloca alguns ``printf()`` no código e descobre em qual linha dá o erro se você não sabe debugar kk, mas acha aí pra gente! Ah, e descreva melhor o que você está querendo fazer.

Comment: Breno, bem vindo ao Soft. Acesse a Ajuda e faça o Tour. Edite sua pergunta, fazendo uma pergunta "clara e objetiva", e se tiver mensagem de erro neste caso, se colocar irá ajudar....

Comment: Porque toda a estrutura que define os dados de um político, sempre deve ter o campo `valorPropina`. :D

Comment: Aqui coloco de forma mais clara o problema. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/139877/problemas-com-%C3%81rvore-bin%C3%A1ria-de-busca-em-c

Answer (score 0):

Vejamos essas duas linhas:

```
no->nomeCompleto = malloc(sizeof(char));
no->nomeCompleto = "sSASs";
```

Ou seja, você alocou um caractere na memória para o `nomeCompleto` e colocou 5 caracteres (mais o terminador da string) na área de memória alocada. Como resultado, você escreveu um dado maior do que a área de memória na qual ele cabe, invadindo então a área de memória subjacente que pertence a alguma outra coisa e corrompendo o conteúdo dela. Como isso significa que o seu programa não respeita os limites de memória a ele alocados, invadindo regiões da memória que não lhe pertencem, o resultado é esse erro que você está tendo.

Para resolver isso, vamos definir um tamanho razoável para a área de memória alocada por cada string:

```
#define MAX_NOME 50
```

```c
no->nomeCompleto = malloc(MAX_NOME * sizeof(char));
no->apelido = malloc(MAX_NOME * sizeof(char));
no->cargo = malloc(MAX_NOME * sizeof(char));
```

E **nunca**, **jamais**, **em hipótese nenhuma** use a função `gets`. Essa função é horrorosa, e é universalmente e unanimemente odiada em meio aos programadores C. O motivo é que é simplesmente impossível utilizar essa função de forma segura. Sempre que ela é usada, o seu programa já ganha de presente um rombo gigantesco pelo qual ele pode falhar catastroficamente da mesma forma como o seu programa está falhando. Não existe forma correta de se utilizar esta função, todas as formas de uso dela são incorretas.

Assim sendo, ao invés de utilizar a função `gets`, utilize a função parecida (porém perfeitamente segura) `fgets`:

```
printf("Nome do politico: ");
fgets(no->nomeCompleto, MAX_NOME, stdin);

printf("Apelido do politico: ");
fgets(no->apelido, MAX_NOME, stdin);

printf("Cargo do politico: ");
fgets(no->cargo, MAX_NOME, stdin);

//printf("Partido do politico: ");
//fgets(no->partido, MAX_NOME, stdin);
```

Assim sendo, eis a sua função de criação:

```
No* criarNo(int id, char* nomeCompleto, char* apelido, char* cargo, /*char *partido,*/ float valor, int qtdDeVezes) {
    No* no = (No*)malloc(sizeof(No));
    no->id = id;
    no->nomeCompleto = malloc(MAX_NOME * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(no->nomeCompleto, nomeCompleto);
    no->apelido = malloc(MAX_NOME * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(no->apelido, apelido);
    no->cargo = malloc(MAX_NOME * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(no->cargo, cargo);
    //no->partido = malloc(MAX_NOME * sizeof(char));
    //strcpy(no->partido, partido);
    no->valorPropina = valor;
    no->qtdVezes = qtdDeVezes;
    no->esq = NULL;
    no->dir = NULL;
    return no;
}
```

E a sua função de destruição:

```
void apagarNo(No *no) {
    free(no->nomeCompleto);
    free(no->apelido);
    free(no->cargo);
    //free(no->partido);
    free(no);
}
```

Só há um detalhe na função de destruição: Ela apenas destroi o nó, mas não o remove da sua árvore binária. Assim sendo, se os nós filhos não tiverem sido previamente removidos, eles ficarão inacessíveis e serão largados esquecidos em algum lugar da memória. Se o nó pai ainda continuar apontando para ele após ele ser removido, então ele apontará para um endereço de memória inválido. Assim sendo, quando você for chamar a função `apagarNo`, primeiramente certifique-se que o nó a ser deletado não seja filho e nem pai de nenhum outro nó, redefinindo as referências pertinentes para garantir isso.