# Ajuda em struct C, não conseguindo alimentar

Tags: c, algoritmo, struct

Galera bom dia, estou criando esse código simples, só pra ler, e exibir, essas informações de um vetor, do tipo `struct`.

Só que ao executar esse código, no ato da execução, não consigo alimentar nem a data nem a filiação, como está explícito na imagem lá em baixo, como se não tivesse espaço entre eles.

Como solucionar?

Segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct bilhete{
  int idade;
  char nome[30];
  char fi[30];
  char data[30];
 };

int main() {
 struct bilhete identidade[5];
int cont;

for (cont = 0 ; cont <=5 ; cont++){
         fflush(stdin);

    printf("Informe o nome: \n");
    gets(identidade[cont].nome);

    printf("Informe a idade: \n");
    scanf("%d",&identidade[cont].idade);

    printf("Informe a filiacao: \n");
    gets(identidade[cont].fi);

    printf("Informe a data: \n");
    gets(identidade[cont].data);

}

// EXIBIR
for (cont =0 ; cont <=5 ; cont++){
    printf("Nome: %s",identidade[cont].nome);
    printf("Idade: %d",identidade[cont].idade);
    printf("Filiacao: %s",identidade[cont].fi);
    printf("Data: %s",identidade[cont].data);

}

system("pause");



return 0;
}
```

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: Leia isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42981/101 e isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111697/101

Comment: [Citando a minha própria resposta em uma outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/139832/132): Nunca, jamais, em hipótese nenhuma use a função `gets`. Essa função é horrorosa, e é universalmente e unanimemente odiada em meio aos programadores C. O motivo é que é simplesmente impossível utilizar essa função de forma segura. Sempre que ela é usada, o seu programa já ganha de presente um rombo gigantesco pelo qual ele pode falhar catastroficamente da mesma forma como o seu programa está falhando. Não existe forma correta de se utilizar esta função, todas as formas de uso dela são incorretas.

Comment: Quanto ao `fflush(stdin)`, veja [essa minha outra resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/96012/132).

Answer (score 2):

Primeiramente, em seu `for`, o `cont` não deve ser `<=` a **5** e sim `<` que **5**. pois todo vetor em *C* vai de **0** a **N-1**.

Os métodos tem tipos diferentes de leitura, o `gets` funciona igual ao `scanf('%[\^n]',...)` a diferença é que no `scanf` você consegue tratar como você quer ler a informação. Para corrigir esse erro, use o `scanf` e passe o seguinte formato para a leitura: `"\n%30[^\n]"`.

Essa instrução não separa os tipos de valores, ele simplesmente lê o que estiver no terminal. Então se coloca o `\n` no começo, faz com que a leitura da informação ocorra depois da quebra de linha (não há necessidade de usar no `%d, %s, %f, %i, %lli, ...`; tem a necessidade de usar em `%[^\n], %c`).

O `%30[^\n]` irá ler os próximos **30** caracteres até a quebra de linha. Como quebra de linha também é caractere, caso não use o `\n` no começo, o leitor identifica uma quebra de linha e entende como se já tivesse lido a instrução, pois isso que o sistema pula a leitura.

```
for (cont = 0 ; cont < 5 ; cont++){
    printf("Informe o nome: ");
    scanf("\n%30[^\n]",identidade[cont].nome);

    printf("Informe a idade: ");
    scanf("%d",&identidade[cont].idade);

    printf("Informe a filiacao: ");
    scanf("\n%30[^\n]",identidade[cont].fi);

    printf("Informe a data: ");
    scanf("\n%30[^\n]",identidade[cont].data);
}
```