# Problemas com árvore binária de busca em C

Tags: c, arquivo, algoritmo-de-busca, árvore

Agora recolocando meu post de forma mais clara (isso é uma continuação da [minha pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/139820/50351)). No código, tento criar uma árvore binária de busca e inserir elementos nela. Os mesmos devem ser salvos em arquivo .txt. Assim que o executo ele fala que o .exe parou de funcionar. Quando comento o método inserir na main, ele roda de boa. Quando debugo ele acusa segmentation fault em `p->id = 1`. Não consigo resolver isso. Segue o meu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_NOME 50

typedef struct politico{
   int id;
   char* nome;
   char* apelido;
//Partido* partido;
   char* cargo;
   float valorPropinaMensal;
   int quantidadeVezes;

   struct politico* esq;
   struct politico* dir;

}Politico;

   Politico* criarP(int id, char* nomeCompleto, char* apelido, char* cargo, float valor, int qtdDeVezes) {

      Politico* politico = (Politico*)malloc(sizeof(politico));

      politico->id = id;

      politico->nome = malloc(MAX_NOME * sizeof(char));
      strcpy(politico->nome, nomeCompleto);
      politico->apelido = malloc(MAX_NOME * sizeof(char));
      strcpy(politico->apelido, apelido);
      politico->cargo = malloc(MAX_NOME * sizeof(char));
      strcpy(politico->cargo, cargo);
      //no->partido = malloc(MAX_NOME * sizeof(char));
      //strcpy(no->partido, partido);
      politico->valorPropinaMensal = valor;
      politico->quantidadeVezes = qtdDeVezes;
      politico->esq = NULL;
      politico->dir = NULL;

    return politico;
  }

Politico* inserirPoliticos(Politico* raiz, int id, char* nome, char* apelido, char* cargo, float valor, int qtdDeVezes){

   Politico* novo = criarP(id , nome, apelido, cargo, valor, qtdDeVezes);
   if(raiz == NULL) return novo;

   Politico* no = raiz;
   Politico* pai = NULL;
   while(no != NULL){
      pai = no;
      if(novo->id < no->id) no = no->esq;
      else no = no->dir;
  }

   if(pai->id > novo->id) pai->esq = novo;
   else pai->dir = novo;

   return raiz;
}

int main(){
   Politico* p = NULL;

   FILE* pEscrita = fopen("politicos.txt","w");

   p->id = 1;
   p->nome="sdwwfw";
   p->apelido="sdvdsvs";
   p->cargo="asasa";

   p->valorPropinaMensal=22.0;
   p->quantidadeVezes= 2;

   p = inserirPoliticos(p, p->id, p->nome, p->apelido, p->cargo, p->valorPropinaMensal, p->quantidadeVezes);

   fprintf(pEscrita,"%d;%s;%s;%s;%.2f;%d", p->id, p->nome, p->apelido, p->cargo, p->valorPropinaMensal, p->quantidadeVezes);

   fclose(pEscrita);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Quando é assim vai isolando o problema. Descomente este método e comente uma parte dentro dele que acha que é onde deu o erro, se for ali, vai cercano o erro, se não for vai trocando de lugar onde comentar. Claro que tem que ter o mínimo de noção do que está fazendo e não ficar comentando coisas aleatórias. Tem que dividir e conquistar até chegar no ponto onde o erro ocorre. Claro que tem maneiras mais profissionais de fazer isto, mas obviamente ainda não sabe como fazer.

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/139820/132 - Aliás, espero que a resposta que eu te dei lá tenha ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Olhe isso:

```
Politico* p = NULL;
p->id = 1;
```

Se `p` é `NULL`, é óbvio que `p->id = 1;` vai dar um *crash*.

Vejamos o que você tenta fazer:

1. No `main` você tenta criar (incorretamente) um `Politico`.
2. Você retira todos os dados deste `Politico` e passa eles um a um para a função `inserirPoliticos`.
3. Na função `inserirPoliticos`, a função `criarP` é chamada.
4. Na função `criarP`, um novo `Politico` é montado novamente com os mesmos dados.

Enfim, você monta o político, desmonta e monta de novo. Isso não é lá muito eficiente. Assim sendo, há duas possíveis abordagens:

1. Você monta o político na `main` e o passa ao `inserirPoliticos` que apenas insere um `Politico` já montado.
2. Você passa os dados brutos para a `inserirPoliticos` e deixa que `inserirPoliticos` monte a estrutura `Politico` ao chamar `criarP`.

Acho que a primeira abordagem é mais limpa, por evitar ter que passar um monte de parâmetros referentes a uma mesma coisa em várias funções diferentes. Assim sendo, a sua função `inserirPoliticos` fica assim:

```
Politico* inserirPoliticos(Politico* raiz, Politico *novo) {
    if (raiz == NULL) return novo;

    Politico* no = raiz;
    Politico* pai = NULL;
    while (no != NULL) {
        pai = no;
        if (novo->id < no->id) {
            no = no->esq;
        } else {
            no = no->dir;
        }
    }

    if (pai->id > novo->id) {
        pai->esq = novo;
    } else {
        pai->dir = novo;
    }

    return raiz;
}
```

E com isso, a `criarP` é usada na função `main`:

```
int main() {
    Politico *novo = criarP(1, "sdwwfw", "sdvdsvs", "asasa", 22.0, 2);
    Politico *raiz = inserirPoliticos(NULL, novo);

    FILE* pEscrita = fopen("politicos.txt", "w");
    fprintf(pEscrita, "%d;%s;%s;%s;%.2f;%d", p->id, p->nome, p->apelido, p->cargo, p->valorPropinaMensal, p->quantidadeVezes);

    fclose(pEscrita);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Deu certo! Era isso mesmo. Bela explicação. Obrigado.